# Using COUNT in GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-concat

This is my table:

```
  id  | fk_company
-------------------
  1   |     2    
  2   |     2    
  3   |     2    
  4   |     4    
  5   |     4    
  6   |     11   
  7   |     11   
  8   |     11   
  9   |     12
```

The result I want should be string "3, 2, 3, 1" (count of items that belong to each company), because this is just part of my complex query string.

I tried to use this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COUNT(id) SEPARATOR ", ")
FROM `table` GROUP BY fk_company;
```

But I got an error:

> Error Number: 1111
> Invalid use of group function

I have a feeling `COUNT`, `MAX`, `MIN` or `SUM` can't be used in `GROUP_CONCAT`.  If so, do you know another way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want this? What happens next?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY` in an inner `SELECT` clause first and then apply `GROUP_CONCAT()`;

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cnt) cnt
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY fk_company
) q;
```

Output:

```
|   CNT   |
-----------
| 3,2,3,1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c83f/3)** demo.

Comment: Thank you very much, I spent a lot of time to fix this. Unfortunately I don't have enough time to play so I needed help even if this result looks so easy.

Comment: Note that this presently relies on the fact that fk_company numbers are arranged sequentially, in a manner that corresponds to id

Answer (score 3):

You can also achieve that by counting the number of commas (or whatever's your separator) in the GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT (LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fk_company))-LENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT fk_company), ',', '')))
FROM `table`
GROUP BY fk_company
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(counts) 
   from (
      select count(id) counts from
          table group by fk_company
   );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT A,  
GROUP_CONCAT(B SEPARATOR '/') AS 'Category',  
GROUP_CONCAT(C SEPARATOR '/') AS 'ALIAS_NAME',COUNT('ALIAS_NAME') AS 'Count'  
FROM carnews  
...  
...
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

This works well in my case.